# easy way to get crispy forms to work with django-filter

Tags: django, django-templates, django-crispy-forms, django-filter

specifically, using the example template in the django-filter docs:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block content %}
<form action="" method="get">
    {{ filter.form.as_p }}
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
{% for obj in filter %}
    {{ obj.name }} - ${{ obj.price }}<br />
{% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

Do others know how to get crispy forms to work?

Inserting the following makes the form render nicely, but I can't get it to actually be functional.

```
{% crispy filter.form %}
```

figured it out - was too easy.  I swear I tried this method several times earlier, although I must have been doing something wrong.  Sorry to ask such a simple question.

Answer is to change:

```
{{ filter.form.as_p }}
```

To:

```
{{ filter.form|crispy }}
```

Answer (score 5):

I just needed to add the load crispy tags.

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}

{% block content %}
    <form action="" method="get">
        {{ filter.form|crispy }}
        <input type="submit" />
    </form>
    {% for obj in filter %}
        {{ obj.name }} - ${{ obj.price }}<br />
    {% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: `{% crispy filter.form %}` also works FWIW. Did you figure out a way to use Crispy Form's `helper.layout = Layout(...)` to define the submit button, field widgets, etc from the Python side?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to also override the layout of the django-filter's filter form, you can override the `form` property on FilterSet class, attach the helper to it and return it.

```
class ValuationFilters(django_filters.FilterSet):
    class Meta:
        model = Valuation
        fields = (
            '...',
        )

    @property
    def form(self):
        form = super().form

        form.helper = FormHelper()
        form.helper.layout = Layout(
            Fieldset(
                'First arg is the legend of the fieldset',
                '...',
            ),
            Submit('submit', 'Submit', css_class='button is-primary'),
        )

        return form
```

Make sure to also use the special cripsy tag instead of `|crispy` template filter for the helper to actually get executed.

```
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}

<form method="get">
    {% crispy filter.form %}
</form>
```

This is in response to Addison Klinke's question on hum3's answer.