# How I can do this search in a crispyforms field?

Tags: python, django, django-crispy-forms

How can I do this search in a crispyforms field?
I read that it could be done with django-filter but I don't know how to integrate it with Crispy-forms.

[enter image description here]

[image: 1]

Comment: i think u'r question is already answered [here!](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22046079/14568649)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLUTION:**

I found the correct solution, there is a library called select2, it allows to make these filters that I needed in my field.

https://django-select2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function () { $('select').selectize({ sortField: 'text' }); });
```

The above Jquery selectize makes searchable select fields, this could be what you are looking for.